# MS Access Syntax Error: When I select the ID in the list table it gives a syntax error with the ID=

Tags: vba, ms-access, migration, salesforce, syntax-error

I am pulling in salesforce tables from a sql server db and the picture below shows how the data types were set. I am using the customer template and the list and detail screens work with the sample tables. However, when I change the table to dbo.case which I have converted to an internal table along with the user table which is used for employees I get the error below. I am trying to figure out why the error happens and I have only changed the tables and made the appropriate changes to map the fields in the form to the new table.

[error message: Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression '[ID]=5001...'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIpFD.png)

[Macro single step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Husok.png)

[Table setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhECH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string value must be wrapped in quotes:

```
[ID]='5001a00000a0FcRAAU'
```

Comment: I knew it was simple. So the where condition is, ="[ID]=" & Nz([ID],0). Do I add the quotes to Nz(["ID"],0) - inside the brackets?

Comment: It shouldn't be needed. If `[ID]` is _Null_, the criteria will not return True.